Flutter Riverpod provider widget not rebuilding
This is my code:
class MealsNotifier extends Notifier<List<Meal>> {

@override
  List<Meal> build() {
    return userMeals;
  }
  updateList(List<Meal> meals) {
    state = List.from(meals);
  }
}

final mealsProvider = NotifierProvider<MealsNotifier, List<Meal>>(() {
  return MealsNotifier();
});

In Categories class I have:
final meals = ref.watch(mealsProvider);

In EditMeal class I have:
ref.read(mealsProvider.notifier).updateList(userMeals);

My app structure is Categories -> Meals -> MealDetails -> EditMeal
After I'm done editing the meal, I expect all these widgets to rebuild since Categories has the ref.watch method.
Edit:
Migrated to Notifier. Still the same issue.
Using the debugger, state is being updated, but nothing rebuilds.

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Can you include the code to show how you use ref.watch inside the widget?

Given the current details, there's no issue in the update mechanism itself.
Check that userMeals argument is updating before passing it.
If Meals is a List of widgets make sure their configuration (params) are enough for Flutter to differentiate between them, otherwise consider using a ValueKey for each one with a suitable value.

There is no issue with updating userMeals. The value of userMeals is changed appropriately, and the updateList method is called. If i exit out of the categories widget, and enter again (thus rebuilding the categories widget manually), everything works as intended and the userMeals list reflects the changes made. My suspicion is that there's an issue with how I implemented the ref.watch method, but I can't figure it out.
